# Android выбор реализации Date format

Tags: java, android, производительность

У меня `recyclerView` с кучей элементов, каждый элемент должен отформатировать и отобразить `Date`, паттерн для всех одинаковый

Есть

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat
android.text.DateFormat
```

`DateFormat` удобен что все делается в одну строку, но как я предполагаю 
`SimpleDateFormat` работает быстрее, ведь ему известен паттерн, а `DateFormat` будет каждый вызов этот паттерн сначала парсить, верное ли предположение ? 
С другой стороны `DateFormat` позволяет не создавать объект, что лучше в такой ситуации ? Или может что - то из них даже лучше во всех ситуациях ?

**Какой из них лучше использовать ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас паттерн всегда один и тот же, то надо создать статический `SimpleDateFormat`

```
static SimpleDateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(MY_PATTERN);
```

тогда вам не надо будет все время его создавать.